# unresolved dependency: com.hanhuy.sbt#android-sdk-plugin;1.3.19: not found

Tags: android, scala, sbt, android-sdk-plugin

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. My `~/.sbt/0.13` looks like:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.hanhuy.sbt" % "android-sdk-plugin" % "1.3.19")
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0")
```

Attempting to `sbt publishLocal` yields:

```
➜  scala  sbt publishLocal
[info] Set current project to scala (in build file:/home/patrick/hacking/scala/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/patrick/hacking/scala/}scala...
[info] Wrote /home/patrick/hacking/scala/target/scala-2.10/scala_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving com.hanhuy.sbt#android-sdk-plugin;1.3.19 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.hanhuy.sbt#android-sdk-plugin;1.3.19
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/patrick/.ivy2/local/com.hanhuy.sbt/android-sdk-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.3.19/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/hanhuy/sbt/android-sdk-plugin_2.10_0.13/1.3.19/android-sdk-plugin-1.3.19.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.hanhuy.sbt#android-sdk-plugin;1.3.19: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.hanhuy.sbt:android-sdk-plugin:1.3.19 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.hanhuy.sbt:android-sdk-plugin:1.3.19 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/home/patrick/.sbt/0.13/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:scala_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.hanhuy.sbt#android-sdk-plugin;1.3.19: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1365)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1399)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1397)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.hanhuy.sbt#android-sdk-plugin;1.3.19: not found
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Apr 6, 2015 2:49:52 AM
```

I have the latest (0.13) version of sbt and the latest (2.11.6) version of Scala installed. I'm new to sbt -- what's missing here?

Comment: can you please check dose you "android-sdk-plugin" plugin compitible with Scala version 2.10? Can you please try with scala's updated vesrion?

Comment: Not an answer, but worth noting: I returned to this about a month later and found that the problem had gone away. When I attempted again, I used a project-local `plugins.sbt`.  I don't know if that's what fixed it, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You've done something that has disabled the default revolvers. Perhaps a bad distribution package otherwise if on Linux.

Also, there is no longer a reason to use sbt-idea with IntelliJ 14+

Comment: I having the same error message trying to use `1.3.22`, with no customization in sbt settings. Is there any value to `resolvers` I can try to make it work?

Comment: It is published to the public community repo. If you are unable to resolve, then your sbt is not installed correctly

Comment: I paste my error message here. Hope you can look at it if you have time to see if there's anything obviously suspicious. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78092/resolve-scala-android-plugin

Comment: @Phil see my new answer

Answer (score 2):

All SBT 0.13 build definitions must be written as scala 2.10

Comment: It works! Thanks! Is it possible to have SBT definitions in scala 2.10 but compile the android project in 2.11.6 otherwise? Sorry I'm an SBT noob.

Comment: Yes, set scalaVersion in the correct place, not in the build definition